# Is opening too many datacontexts bad?

Tags: asp.net, performance, linq-to-sql, optimization

I've been checking my application with linq 2 sql profiler, and I noticed that it opens a lot of datacontexts, most of them are opened by the linq datasource I used, since my repositories use only the instance stored in Request.Items, is it bad to open too many datacontext? and how can I make my linqdatasource to use the datacontext that I store in Request.Items for the duration of the request? thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open and close them, absolutely not.

But if you're inside a TransactionScope, the game changes!  Opening and closing many nested DataContexts bit us hard because it caused our transactions to promote to distributed transactions, which slowed down our system quite a bit and severely cut our system's scalability.

Answer (score 1):

DataContexts are intended to have short lifetime. Opening many of them is not necessarily a bad thing. A good rule of thumb is that each "unit of work" should have its own DataContext.

See this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/dinesh.kulkarni/archive/2008/04/27/lifetime-of-a-linq-to-sql-datacontext.aspx) for more details.

> It is better to err on the side of shorter lifetime